# How to vertically merge dataframes on matching column value

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I am sending 15 minute audio files of 2 person conversations to a transcription/speaker diarization service. Circumstances require me chunk 15 minute files into three 5 minute files. Unfortunately, speaker labels are not consistent across chunks, but I need them to be for analysis.

For example, in the first file, speakers are labeled '0' and '1'. However, in the second file, they are labeled '1' and '2'. In the third file, they may be labeled '1' and '0' respectively. This is a problem as I need consistent labeling.

My current approach is to represent data from each chunk in a dataframe. To have a reference for labels across dataframes, I overlapped each dataframe by 10 seconds. I want to merge each dataframe where 'transcript', 'start', and/or 'start' columns match.

Then, I want to modify the speaker labeling scheme on the newly merged dataframe to match the previous dataframe based on the overlapping values.

This is what dataframe 1 looks like:

> df

```
                transcript  start  stop  speaker_label
0              hello world    1.2   2.2              0
1  why hello, how are you?    2.3   4.0              1
2          fine, thank you    4.1   5.0              0
```

This is what dataframe 2 looks like. Note how the first row matches the last row in the previous dataframe because of the overlapping, but now the speaker_label scheme is different.

> df1

```
                          transcript  start  stop  speaker_label
0                    fine, thank you    4.1   5.0              1
1          you?(should be speaker 0)    5.1   6.0              1
2  good, thanks(should be speaker 1)    6.1   7.0              2
```

This is what I want, dataframes vertically merged where 'start' values match, and having the 'df1' 'speaker_label' scheme match the scheme of 'df'.

> ideal_df

```
                          transcript  start  stop  speaker_label
0                        hello world    1.2   2.2              0
1            why hello, how are you?    2.3   4.0              1
2                    fine, thank you    4.1   5.0              0
3          you?(should be speaker 0)    5.1   6.0              0
4  good, thanks(should be speaker 1)    6.1   7.0              1
```

Comment: `pd.concat([df,df1], ignore_index=True).drop_duplicates('transcript')` ?

Comment: Thanks @harvpan, this solves my first problem of joining dataframes. Now I need to match 'speaker_label' schemes between dataframes.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `pd.concat` to merge/concat vertically. You can refer to [Pandas merging concat join examples](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/merging.html)

```
ideal_df=pd.concat([df,df1])
ideal_dfdrop_duplicates(keep='first',inplace=True)
```

Comment: This would result in duplicates.

Comment: @harvpan, you are right. I have made changes to drop the duplicates. My apology!!

Answer (score 0):

Try to do ;) :

```
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'c1':['titi','toto','tutu'], 'c2': [0,1,0]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'c1':['tata','tete','titi'], 'c2': [1,1,0]})

df = pd.concat([df1, df2])
df.drop_duplicates(keep='first')
```